# Firebase success but no notification received

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I got my app running and notification works fine at first. But after a while it just stopped.

I tried sending through the Firebase console and it returns success, but no notification was received by the application. The application was in background, and it worked earlier, no code has been changed on either the app or the server side.

If I reinstalled the app (getting a new token), the notification would return to normal (working as intended), but if the token expires shouldn't the Firebase console return an error (registration token error or something)?

And it has only been a few days since I used the application, so why would the token expires (documentation said token would expire in 6 months)? 
And I know it is a bad approach to actually force a token refresh every time a user runs my app.

So did I do something wrong? Cause if I debug my app everything works fine. Got the token, got the notification.

And yeah, sending notification through FCM console and via server yield the same result; success, but no notification.

the onTokenRefresh code looklike this :

```
  namespace FCMClient
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
        public override void OnTokenRefresh()
        {
            var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
            SendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        }
        void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
        {
            //a post request to my server 

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Hi Sulaeman. It's hard to pinpoint anything without seeing any code snippets (possibly in `onTokenRefresh()` or at the very least a sample payload. Also, could you point out to me where in the documentation you saw the "*documentation said token would expire in 6 months*"?

Comment: my onTokenrefresh is exactly like those here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#client_app

and the documentation i've seen it somewhere .. i'll look it up again. on

Comment: OnTokenRefresh is invoked infrequently: it is used to update the token under the following circumstances:

    When the app is installed or uninstalled.
    When the user deletes app data.
    When the app erases the Instance ID.

    When the security of the token has been compromised.

According to Google's Instance ID documentation, the FCM Instance ID service will request that the app refresh its token periodically (typically, every 6 months). 
this is according to : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/

Comment: I understand the behavior pretty well. What I was going to advise is on is to double check if you are actually sending the refreshed token towards your App server? I see a `//a post request to my server` comment, but are you able to receive it on Server side?

Comment: Yes @AL im able to get the token. And the notification have worked several times with that token. Then without any change in code in the cllient or the server it stopped working. And i cant receive any notification even when i directly use the token via firebase console. ( i cant pinpoint when exactly, and the firebase console returns success but no notification). But if i clear app data (get new token) it will work again and i can receive notification again.

Answer (score 1):

This always happens to my, it's a kind of bug or something, i have to clean and rebuild every time, this not happen on release, you can delete the firebase instance and get a new token everytime you run the application while you'r debugging.

you can write this on you oncreate

```
Task.Run(() => {  
var instanceid = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance;  
instanceid.DeleteInstanceId();  
Log.Debug("TAG", "{0} {1}", instanceid.Token, instanceid.GetToken(this.GetString(Resource.String.gcm_defaultSenderId), Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.InstanceIdScope)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the debug fingerprint in Firebase console seems to do the trick.